# Extract coordinates of matching text in PDF

Tags: bash, grep, libraries, pdf

Basically I want to grep a string in a PDF and get the **coordinates** of the matching result(s).

I already use `pdftotext` to do the opposite, namely to extract some text given its coordinates.

In Scheme I found a library - developed upon `Poppler`, if I recall correctly - that does what I want, but I need to use such functionality in bash.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a solution in a different language, the obvious solution is to write a utility program in that language which you can then call from `bash`.

Comment: @Tom Hunt the coordinate values in Scheme differ from the one used by `pdftotext`. I cannot mix the 2 solutions and the bash library works much better, I need to use that.